# apply css to grid view on click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I was trying to apply background color to grid view row, when clicked on that particular grid view row.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeRowColor(objref) {
            objref.style.backgroundcolor = "red";
        }
    </script>


 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            string rowID = String.Empty;

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeRowColor(this)");
            }

        }
```

But, when i click on that row, nothing was happening..Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the case wrong.

it should be as below.

```
objref.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: try to find out if the function is getting called at all .. put an alert() in the js function.

Comment: Yes, it is working now..but the problem is when i click on that row, it is changed to that color..But, when i click on another row, the other row , the previously selected row is not changed to normal color..can you give any sugesstions on this..

Comment: You could use a hidden field to track the previously selected row and each time you set a new row, you set the previous row back to the original background color.

Comment: Your question doesn't cover this scenario though .. might be best to ask a new question or update your current question .. and you should accept my answer if it solved your problem (initial one) :)